# Compilation error: "nested name specifier for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization"

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, enable-if

I have 2 files:

**digest.hpp**

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<DigestCreator, T>>>
class DigestHolder {
public:
    DigestHolder();
};
#include "digest.ipp" // Included here.
```

**digest.ipp**

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<DigestCreator, T>>>
DigestHolder<T>::DigestHolder()
{};
```

The class is decleared in `hpp` file and defined in `ipp` file. The `ipp` file is included at the end of `hpp` file.

However, I get compilation error:

```
error: nested name specifier 'DigestHolder<T>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
DigestHolder<T>::DigestHolder()
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I tried by modifying the `hpp` template declaration as below but no good result:

Attempt 1:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<DigestCreator, T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr> 
class DigestHolder {};
```

Attempt 2:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<DigestCreator, T>, bool> = true> 
class DigestHolder {};
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]. I tried to add the missing pieces but at some point I gave up https://godbolt.org/z/bTfT8Txcx

Comment: also it is unclear why you want to define the constructor twice

Comment: fwiw, if the template code is sufficient to reproduce the error then you can put it all in once file. `#include` merely includes all contents of one file in another file, hence it should not be needed for the example

Comment: @mch the implementation is in `ipp` file and not is source file. Also, the ipp is included in hpp file below.

Comment: Don't duplicate the answer in your question. It's not part of the question.

Answer (score 6):

The template has two parameters even though you provide a default for one of them.
You need to name the second parameter in order to refer to it in the definition, and you should not provide another default argument:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
DigestHolder<T, U>::DigestHolder() {}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I updated my question with the answer too.

Comment: Don't duplicate the answer in your question, accept this answer instead.